# Nextjs project not deploying to Vercel

Tags: github, next.js, vercel, trpc

Hi I recently encountered the following error when publishing my nextjs project to VERCEL.

Error: "ReferenceError: File is not defined"

I got the error in my API routes, I deleted my routes and published it again in Vercel. I did trial and error for several days, each time the error came out on a different route, why?... I don't know.

[VERCEL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcQoT.png)

After reading articles I came up with possible causes.

1- I needed to update Node or NextJs (It didn't solve anything)

2- It was wrong to import zod schemas to my api, I thought it was something related to the client side. (It didn't solve anything)

3- Prisma cannot be called in API, because it is imported as "import { Prisma, publication } from "@prisma/client";
". (It didn't solve anything)

4- Trpc is causing the error, because I call the routes from a trpc call. (It didn't solve anything)

None of my hypotheses above solved anything, until within an API route I found the origin of the problem.

I realized that in api/caption/route.ts, the problem was originating, and the problem was that I was importing the generateCaption function from lib/utils.ts.

api/caption/route.ts:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import { db } from "@/lib/prisma";

import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai"
import { PrismaVectorStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/prisma"
import { Prisma, publication } from "@prisma/client";
import { formattedText } from "@/lib/utils";
import { postPublicationSchema } from "@/lib/schemas/publication";

// POST
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {

    try {
        const body = await req.json()

        // Get data
        const { userId, data } = body

        // Validate data in body
        const validInputs = postPublicationSchema .parse(data)

        // Verify userId 
        if (!userId) throw new Error("Invalid userId")

        // Validate API KEY
        const headersInstance = headers()
        const authorization = headersInstance.get('authorization')
        if (!authorization || authorization !== process.env.API_KEY) throw new Error('Invalid API_KEY')
        //

        // Data validated
        const inputEmbedding = formattedText(generateCaption(data))

        // Logic

        // Store embeddings
        const vectorStore = PrismaVectorStore.withModel<publication>(db).create(
            new OpenAIEmbeddings({
                openAIApiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY
            }),
            {
                prisma: Prisma,
                tableName: "publication",
                vectorColumnName: "embedding",
                columns: {
                    id: PrismaVectorStore.IdColumn,
                    embeddingContent: PrismaVectorStore.ContentColumn,
                },
            }
        );

        await vectorStore.addModels(
            await db.$transaction(
                [
                    db.publication.create({
                        data: {
                            ...validInputs, // pass inputs valid data
                            userId: userId,
                            embeddingContent: inputEmbedding,
                        }
                    })
                ]
            )
        );

        return new NextResponse("Success", { status: 200 })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(" POST publication ERROR: ", error)
        return new NextResponse("Error", { status: 500 })
    } finally {
        console.log("✅ POST publication SUCCESS")
    }
}
```

lib/schemas.ts:

```
import { z } from "zod";

export const postPublicationSchema = z.object({
    header: z.string().min(10).max(100),
    description: z.string().min(50).max(500),
})
```

lib/utils.ts:

```
import { postPublicationSchema } from "./schemas/publication";
import { format } from 'date-fns';

export function generateCaption(data: any): string {

  const validInputs = postPublicationSchema.parse(data)

  const property = CaptionType.find((op) => op.value === validInputs)?.label

  return `
  ${validInputs.header} .....
  `
}
```

I have already tried several times to upload the project to Vercel with the function imported into the api and the error appears, and when I remove the function the error is removed. BECAUSE???

I don't know if it's important but I use trpc.

In this image you can see the error, in this case it shows that the error is the sign-in route, but on that route there is no error, other times I got a different route.

[VERCEL ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcQoT.png)

Why is this function generating an error in VERCEL?

What's wrong with my code? Please help me understand.

Thanks

I suspect that the error is related to zod, because within the generateCaption function it is still called zod parse. But why???

Comment: If it works locally for you and builds successfully, but crashes on Vercel. I suggest try commenting out, and removing new npm packages like prisma.  To see if you can get working version.  I had issues in the past there Vercel would crash due to npm package.And try working forward by uncommenting until you discover issue. The other solution is to implement sentry to see errors in production. However for me they not always helpful for debuging vercel crashes.

Comment: @ArnasDičkus Thanks, I have been trying and i found that importing zod to a Api route, causes the error, is that a bad thing?

Comment: Depends. Zod should work in node.js. So I would check if you import empty zod would it still crash. Next I would replace any with type generateCaption(data: any) and add if statement if(data) do stuff.

Comment: @ArnasDičkus Great! Thanks